# Nested Template Fragments with Custom Queries?

Tags: sql, templates, documentation-generation, enterprise-architect

First, in the Sparx help I read under 'Creating a Template Fragment':

"*If you embed a Template Fragment within another Fragment, report generation from the parent template will be slower*".

So, I understand that nesting template fragments should be possible, in general.

I have a number of diagrams from which I want to generate documentation.
For each diagram, I want to process the elements of certain types (e.g. activities) on that diagram.
Therefore, my primary template (which processes the diagram), references a template fragment that is based on a custom query:

```
select o.Name as ActivityName, ...
from t_object o, t_diagramobjects do
where 
   o.Object_ID = do.Object_ID 
   and do.Diagram_ID = #DIAGRAMID# 
   and o.Object_Type = 'Activity'
```

That works - I can for instance insert custom field {ActivityName} in the Template Fragment.

However, I would also like to query the *tagged values of an object linked to each activity*...
For this I have another template fragment based on a custom query, looking like this:

```
select op.Property as LinkedTagName, op.Value as LinkedTagValue
from 
   t_object o1, t_connector c, t_object o2, t_objectproperties op
where
   o1.Object_ID = #OBJECTID#
   and o1.Object_ID = c.Start_Object_ID
   and c.End_Object_ID = o2.Object_ID
   and o2.Object_ID = op.Object_ID
```

Used directly, this second template fragment also works fine, and I can build a table referencing {TagName} and {TagValue}

However, what I cannot figure out is how to make both work together, so the second template fragment nested in the first one, so that for each diagram element, I can also show the linked tagged values.

Probably the 'inner' custom query does not receive an #OBJECTID# ?
I tried a.o. to return OBJECTID as a field in the 'outer' custom query, but that does not make any difference.

Is it somehow possible to have nested template fragments with custom queries...?

Comment: I think your SQL queries would be a lot easier to read if you use proper `join` syntax. See my answer for some examples.

Comment: You have a point there :o) When diving into a data model that I'm not yet familiar with, I always start off with the basic syntax - not sure if that's a good reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your fragment should be used in the element section under the diagram, but EA doesn't allow that

```
package >
Package Name: {Pkg.Name}
diagram >
Diagram name: {Diagram.Name}
element >
The fragment should be added here but EA doesn't allow that
< element
< diagram
< package
```

I guess you then added it to the `diagram>` section, but that won't work as it will not have the `#OBJECTID#` available.

Possible solutions

1. Use the `#DIAGRAMID#` in your fragment and create one big table for all elements and their tagged values in the diagram
   You can use a query such as

   `select o.[Name] AS Owner, tv.[Property] as TV_Name, tv.[VALUE] AS TV_Value, tv.[Notes] as TV_Notes 
   from (((t_object o
   inner join t_diagramObjects dob on dob.[Object_ID] = o.[Object_ID])
   inner join t_diagram d on dob.[Diagram_ID] = d.[Diagram_ID])
   left join t_objectproperties tv on tv.[Object_ID] = o.[Object_ID])
   where d.[Diagram_ID] = #DIAGRAMID#`

Then add you SQL Fragment to the Diagram Section of your template

```
package >
Package Name: {Pkg.Name}
diagram >
Diagram name: {Diagram.Name}
{My SQL Template Fragment}
< diagram
< package
```

2. Use a Virtual Document where you add a model document for the diagram part of your template, and you add a model document for the elements part of the template. In that case you can use an SQL search to define the elements that should be reported by the fragment. Use something like:

   `select o.[ea_guid] AS CLASSGUID, o.[Object_Type] AS CLASSTYPE, o.[Name] as Name
   from ((t_object o
   inner join t_diagramObjects dob on dob.[Object_ID] = o.[Object_ID])
   inner join t_diagram d on dob.[Diagram_ID] = d.[Diagram_ID])
   where d.[ea_guid] = '<Search Term>'`

Put the name of the search in the tagged value `SearchName` and put the GUID of the diagram (right click on diagram in project browser and choose `Copy/Paste..|Copy Node GUID to clipboard`) in the tagged value `SearchValue`

Then make a normal template and use something like

```
package >
element >
Element Name: {Element.Name}
tagged value >
Tagged Value Name: {ElementTagVal.Name} 
Tagged Value Value: {ElementTagVal.Value}
Tagged Value Notes: {ElementTagVal.Notes}
< tagged value
< element
< package
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate response!

* I don't see what you mean by "EA doesn't allow that"? My fragment is in package>element, and that works.. Also in package>diagram>element it seems to work?

* Solution 1 with a big table is not really an option - there will be other things in-between.

* Solution 2 seems possible, but I'll have many diagrams with different element types per diagram, so it's practically not very feasible to do this *manually*. However, I see elsewhere that you suggest to *generate* virtual docs, and that indeed would be the perfect solution - so I'll mark this as answer.

Comment: Forgot to mention: for myself (and until I create such a virtual document generation script ;o) I found this workaround: I have only one element type for which I need the nested fragment. So, I ended up running that 'outer' fragment *without* custom query on all diagram elements, with a nested template fragment annex custom query inside it but with a filter on the right element type, and then create separate template fragments *with* custom queries for the other element types. 
Hope I'm making myself clear...

Comment: "EA doesn't allow that" means I don't get the option to add a script fragment in the context menu if I right click in the `Package>Diagram>Element` section.